# Improve SELECT with an "OR" condition to avoid costly Seq Scan in Postgres and make it Index Scan?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-indexes

I have a table `attributes` that has `name`, `value`, `unit_id` and `pers_id` fields.

I have also index such as:

```
CREATE INDEX  attrs_index ON attributes (name, value, unit_id);
```

When I perform EXPLAIN as follows

```
EXPLAIN select "value", "pers_id"
                 from "attributes"
                 where "name" = 'somename' and ("unit_id" = 'UNIT100' or "unit_id" = '0');
```

I, however, receive the answer that a Seq Scan would happen with a large cost.

```
Seq Scan on attributes  (cost=0.00..1276004.95 rows=4553854 width=23)
Filter: ((name = 'somename'::text) AND ((unit_id = 'UNIT100'::text) OR (unit_id = '0'::text)))
```

How I should proceed to reduce it to a faster/ less costly query?

Comment: How many rows does the table have? It seems the optimizer expects the condition to return a large percentage of the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name orders of millions

Comment: Well the optimizers expects that your condition results in 4.5 million rows to be returned. Your condition apparently doesn't really reduce the number of rows substantially so a Seq Scan seems like the best option. If that estimate is completely wrong, try to run `analyze attributes;` and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

You're only using `name` and `unit_id` in your query, so you might get better results using an index created in that order:

```sql
CREATE INDEX  attrs_index ON attributes (name, unit_id, value);
```

instead of what you currently have:

```sql
CREATE INDEX  attrs_index ON attributes (name, value, unit_id);
```

(It's probably worth running `ANALYZE` on this table after creating this index, if it's not been done.)

Quoting the documentation on [multi-column indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-multicolumn.html) (emphasis mine):

> **A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost) columns.** The exact rule is that equality constraints on leading columns, plus any inequality constraints on the first column that does not have an equality constraint, will be used to limit the portion of the index that is scanned. Constraints on columns to the right of these columns are checked in the index, so they save visits to the table proper, but they do not reduce the portion of the index that has to be scanned. For example, given an index on (a, b, c) and a query condition WHERE a = 5 AND b >= 42 AND c < 77, the index would have to be scanned from the first entry with a = 5 and b = 42 up through the last entry with a = 5. Index entries with c >= 77 would be skipped, but they'd still have to be scanned through. **This index could in principle be used for queries that have constraints on b and/or c with no constraint on a — but the entire index would have to be scanned, so in most cases the planner would prefer a sequential table scan over using the index.**

It might also be worth trying `unit_id IN ('UNIT100','0')` if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your index cannot be used efficiently because

- `value` is before `unit_id` in the index
- there is an `OR` in your `WHERE` condition

Create an index on only `(name, unit_id)` and change the query to

```
SELECT value, pers_id
FROM attributes
WHERE name = 'somename'
  AND unit_id IN ('UNIT100', '0');
```

Comment: How is `IN` treated differently than `OR`?

Comment: PostgreSQL can use a simple index scan for an `IN` condition, but has to do a bitmap index scan with bitmap or for an `OR`. And no, there is no special code that checks if the same column is used twice.